# How to create Small Customized UIView in a Main View when I press UIButton?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton

Dear Friend How  can i create small Customized  UIView in a main View when I Click New/Add View Button and i need to give text for label that should br stored dynamically i.e when ever i open the application that  View and  corresponding Text for that view.

Finally  i need to arrange like

```
                     A      B
                     C      D
                     E      F
                     etc,,
```

here ABCDEF are UIView with text Label...

Please suggest some idea to  me how can i implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in .h file add this

```
NSString * LRStr;
int count;
int y;
```

and in .m file

```
    -(void)viewDidLoad
        {
        LRStr = @"left";
        count=0;
        y=0;
        }

        - (IBAction)addView:(id)sender {


        if(count == 2 )
        {
        y=y+60;
        count = 0;
        }

            if ([LRStr isEqualToString:@"left"])
        {
           UIView * bGView = [[UIView alloc] init];
            bGView.frame = CGRectMake(10,y,50,50);
            bGView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            bGView.alpha = 0.8 ;
            [self.view addSubview:bGView];

            UILabel * alabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
            alabel.text = @"Write here";
            alabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
            alabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            alabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
           [bGView addSubview:alabel];
    LRStr = @"right"
        }else
        {
        UIView * bGView = [[UIView alloc] init];
            bGView.frame = CGRectMake(260,y,50,50);
            bGView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            bGView.alpha = 0.8 ;
            [self.view addSubview:bGView];

            UILabel * alabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
            alabel.text = @"Write here";
            alabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
            alabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            alabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
           [bGView addSubview:alabel];
    LRStr = @"left"
        }

 count++;
        }
```

Comment: above program quit ok but the first row  only left side  view only added not right side after count 1 its take break

Comment: just add count++ to end not beginning ,my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

On the button click event create UIView programatically with frames according to what you need 
You can add the Label in the view in the loop itself or create a subclass of UIView to have the label in it and add this view to the main view in the loop .